# WebClient alternative for windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows, webclient

I use `WebClient` to fetch Yahoo data for Windows Phone 8 and Android
 HttpClient With WebClient I can do

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.DownloadStringCompleted += new     DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

after sending event;

```
   StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result)

   XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
   reader.ReadToFollowing("yweather:atmosphere");
   string humidty = reader.MoveToAttribute("humidity");
```

but in Windows 8 RT there is no such thing.

how can I fetch the following data? >http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2343732&u=c

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HttpClient class, something like this :

```
public async static Task<string> GetHttpResponse(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Windows 8 app client");

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    else
     throw new Exception("Error connecting to " + url +" ! Status: " + response.StatusCode);
}
```

Simpler version would be just :

```
public async static Task<string> GetHttpResponse(string url)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

But if http error occurs GetStringAsync will throw HttpResponseException, and as far I can see there is no http status indicated except in exception message.

UPDATE:
I didn't noticed that you in fact you are trying to read RSS Feed, you don't need HttpClient and XML parser, just use SyndicationFeed class, here is the example :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452994.aspx

Comment: Or use `await client.GetStringASync`... there's no need to check the status code yourself.

Comment: I presume that GetStringASync will throw exception if fails (WebException) ? There is nothing in MSDN docs about that

Comment: Well, the task returns by GetStringAsync will fault. I agree it should be better documented.

Comment: [meta]@AntonioBakula thanks for httpclient, but i first time hear to,for example; with webclient i can
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);



                reader.ReadToFollowing("yweather:atmosphere");
                //Populate Temperature

                reader.MoveToAttribute("humidity"); i can find humidty values of current, of yahoo weather rss, with httpclient how i can take of humidty?[/meta]

Comment: there is no WebClient class on WinRT, you should use XDocument and parse returned string from GetHttpResponse method above, if content is XML of course.

Comment: @AntonioBakula can you give a sample with string of return gethttpresponse , if you can do it i can use it with gethttpresponse

Comment: I didn't noticed that you want to read RSS feed, look at this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452994.aspx