# Metro Apps: C#, read text file from internet

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

what I want is simple, I want to read a text file from my website via my application, I managed to do this in C# but not in metro apps, here my code in C#

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(strURL);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
return content;
```

besides the above code I also tried the code below, but still failed

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(strURL);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
string tempString = null;
int count = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

do
{
  count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
  if (count != 0)
  {
    tempString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf, 0, count);
    sb.Append(tempString);
  }
}
return sb.ToString();
```

I think the problem is in the WebClient and GetResponse () which is not known in metro apps

Comment: why not `WebClient.DownloadString(url)` ?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found, i think WebClient class is not in the metro-ui apps

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191984/webclient-alternative-for-windows-8

Comment: ok, thanks, i will see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use System.Net.Http.HttpClient and HttpResponseMessage, as they are included on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454046.aspx.

There is an example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx:

```
static async void Main()
{
    try 
    {
      // Create a New HttpClient object.
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method in following line 
      // string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

      Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }  
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!"); 
      Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
 }
```

Comment: i try it with localhost adress, and i get this "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set."

Answer (score 1):

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Wrapped up in an async method of course